# How to sort Integer that are Strings?

Tags: java, arrays, string, collections, integer

I have this project where I have a variable called "Floor" as a String. My task is to sort the floor **asc** and **desc** way to show on the Recycler View.

My Json response contains the following element:

"floor": 1

I have this options **asc** and **desc** inside a spinner so I will show you the swicth case correspondent:

```
 case ASC:
       //Sort array list into Ascending order.
       Collections.sort(listModelsUa);
       listModelsUa.add(modelUA);
 case DESC:
       Collections.reverse(listModelsUa);
       listModelsUa.add(modelUA);
```

Note: My ModelUA implements Comparable and overrides the following method

```
String floor;

    @Override
        public int compareTo(@NonNull Object o) {
            int compareTo=((ModelUA )o).getFloor();
            /* For Ascending order*/
            return this.floor-compareTo;
        }
```

My question is,there are any other way to sort values inside an ArrayList using strings(maybe cast to Int) and displaying in the Recycler view?

Comment: Parse the strings into integer. For example by using `Integer.parseInt(text);`. Then you can sort them like integer.

Comment: Why does your `ModelUA` implement `Comparable` instead of `Comparable<ModelUA>`? Or, why do you have `Object` in your `compareTo` method? Use generics, not raw types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to convert string to integer as below. Then you can sort or reverse it.

```
int[] myIntArray = new int[myarray.length];

for (int i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
    myIntArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(myarray[i]);
}
Collections.sort(myIntArray);
```

If you want to sort in alphabetical order using core java then use code as below.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) 
        {
            if (names[i].compareTo(names[j])>0) 
            {
                temp = names[i];
                names[i] = names[j];
                names[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Names in Sorted Order:");
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
    {
        System.out.print(names[i] + ",");
    }
```

OR

```
 Collections.sort(Arrays.stream(myIntArray).stream()
.map(i -> Integer.parseInt(i))
.distinct()
.collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[`Stream.map()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html)** to parse the `Strings` then sort the list.

This is how should be your code:

```
Collections.sort(listModelsUa.stream()
    .map(i -> Integer.parseInt(i))
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Note that instead of the lambda `i -> Integer.parseInt(i)` you can use a method reference `Integer::parseInt`.

Comment: @Zabuza Yes thank you for pointing it out,  I know I posted it like this just to simplify things.